# Sharemouse not working after mac update

Tags: sharemouse

I really don't like to update OS's because stuff like this happens BUT I had to update my mac for certain programs to work (like Xcode).

I'd tried to flip through all the mac preferences I could think of to get my PC keyboard to work on mac via sharemouse but no luck.

List of Issues

- mouse works fine, both ways, except for right click actions eg copy/paste
- mac keyboard works fine on pc
- pc keyboard DOES NOT work on mac

**Question**

Has anyone else had issues like this since update mac to Ventura (13.5) ?

*extras*

- PC is 64bit Intel based windows 11
- mac is m1 air
- sharmouse is 5.0.49 Pro

Comment: Have you contacted sharemouse? Have you followed the Ventura instructions at [ShareMouse - Installation](https://www.sharemouse.com/doc/installation/#mac)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Great followup. Unfortunately I had already set all the preferences so that's not it. I tried to reach out to ShareMouse but it seems my Pro license has fallen out of maintenance.